# Fedora Bluetooth

Tags: fedora, bluetooth

Which packets do I have to install for my bluetooth headset to work? 
I have installed:

```
rpm -qa |grep blue
bluez-alsa-4.99-2.fc17.i686
bluez-libs-4.99-2.fc17.i686
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth-1.1-9.fc17.i686
blueman-1.23-2.fc17.i686
bluez-4.99-2.fc17.i686
bluez-hcidump-2.2-2.fc17.i686
gnome-bluetooth-libs-3.4.2-1.fc17.i686
bluez-compat-4.99-2.fc17.i686
bluez-cups-4.99-2.fc17.i686
bluez-hid2hci-4.99-2.fc17.i686
bluez-gstreamer-4.99-2.fc17.i686
```

I can connect and pair to my headset but I haven't an option to select headset as sound device for sound output in sound applications
when i get connected to headset my volume property where i could select output devices becomes unavailable, screen-shot below 
[image: pulseaudio volume properties]